# iOS team "Agent" or "User"

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm running iOS app in simulator and it is asking me to sign in to my account.  When I sign in there are 2 choices

```
name ----------------- Agent
name (Personal Team)-- User
```

which do I pick and what is the differences between them?

Similar to 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Art/2_aboutaccountsprefs_2x.png

but I have 2 choices instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

if your Developer account is Registered with Company then select a "AGENT" , if you Register Personal in Apple developer Then select a "USER"

Visit :

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/

you can Find there

Comment: why would i have 2 choices?  Did I register twice?

Answer (score 0):

I have two options too for my apple ID which should I call it two teams.
one for my own dev accounts, the other one is my company's. My company's account add me to the develop group as a member, so I can access that.

They are completely different team. so, I can get two team's resource.
one for my own, one for work.

you can choose it in the target->General->Signing->team for the correct project.